# Having trouble with the sort command outputting everything multiple times

Tags: bash, sorting, lexicographic

I've got a temp file made with mktemp. Before the script exits, I must ouput the contents of the file to the screen. The contents have to be lexicographically sorted. When I try to apply sort to the temp file, it outputs a sorted result multiple times.
i.e. My temp file looks like this without sorting

```
OUT="$(mktemp)"
#Add lines to $OUT
cat "$OUT"
```

This outputs

```
../a1q2/hello1.cc
../a1q2/hello2.cpp
../a1q2/hello3.h
../a1q2/hello4.C
../a1q2/z/hi.cc
../a1q2/dir/two.cpp
../a1q2/dir/one.cc
../a1q2/dir/three.h
../a1q2/dir/four.C
../extra/dir/hi.cpp
../extra/dir/hi2.C
../extra/hi.cc
../extra/h2.cc
../extra/h3.h
```

I'd like to sort this lexicographically, but when I do

```
OUT="$(mktemp)"
#Add some lines to $OUT ...
sort "$OUT"
cat "$OUT"
```

I get the following output

```
../a1q2/dir/four.C
../a1q2/dir/one.cc
../a1q2/dir/three.h
../a1q2/dir/two.cpp
../a1q2/hello1.cc
../a1q2/hello2.cpp
../a1q2/hello3.h
../a1q2/hello4.C
../a1q2/z/hi.cc
../extra/dir/hi.cpp
../extra/dir/hi2.C
../extra/h2.cc
../extra/h3.h
../extra/hi.cc
../a1q2/hello1.cc
../a1q2/hello2.cpp
../a1q2/hello3.h
../a1q2/hello4.C
../a1q2/z/hi.cc
../a1q2/dir/two.cpp
../a1q2/dir/one.cc
../a1q2/dir/three.h
../a1q2/dir/four.C
../extra/dir/hi.cpp
../extra/dir/hi2.C
../extra/hi.cc
../extra/h2.cc
../extra/h3.h
```

I don't know why this is happening. Any help at all would be appreciated

Comment: Remove `cat "$OUT"`.

Answer (score 1):

`sort` outputs to STDOUT, it does not overwrite the file you sorted.

You probably meant to do something like:

```
sort "$OUT" > sorted.txt
cat sorted.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine two steps with `tee`, sorted output will be written to a file and to STDOUT.

```
$ sort file | tee sorted_file
```